# How connect to Teradata using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, teradata

I'm attempting to connect to Teradata through VBA:

```vb
Sub sql_query()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rc As ADODB.Recordset
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
On Error GoTo Invalid
Cn.Open "Driver={Teradata};DBCname=TDPREPE01;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxx!;"
Invalid:
MsgBox ("There was error number " & Err.Number & ". This is " & Err.Description & ".")

End Sub
```

I get the following error:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I logged in with the correct credentials as it is the same credentials to login to mySQL.

Screenshot of my active connection:
[image]

Comment: Teradata no longer offers an OLEDB Provider (and using the Microsoft SQL Server specific provider won't work). Consider using Teradata's ODBC driver (available from downloads.teradata.com).

Comment: I just updated my query but encountering an issue as it states wrong username/password while I know its correct.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to display errors. Doing so forces us to type in the text so we can search for it, instead of being able to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point is to set an authentication or there will be no connection.

The following worked:

```
Sub sql_query()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rc As ADODB.Recordset
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={Teradata};DBCname=TDPREP01;Uid=C121009;Pwd=Internet2022!; Authentication=LDAP;"
```

End Sub

Comment: So you are using an old version of Teradata driver. Current versions have names like Driver={Teradata Database ODBC Driver 17.20}. And yes, if you need LDAP authentication you typically need to specify that, since default is usually TD2.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I had feeling that this might have been an older one. I could try to do so and test. Fred feel free to share your answer as mentioned in comment and id be more than happy to vote your answer :)